# pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

Hi I have a SQL query which gives results like the following table

```
ID   NAME   problem_ID   date_of_entry    elem_id   staff_id    
1    abc     456          12/12/2014      789          32
1    abc     768          12/01/2014      896          67
1    abc     897          02/14/2014      875          98
2    bcd     723          02/17/2014      287          09
2    bcd     923          09/13/2014      879          01
2    bcd     878          08/23/2014      hgd          34
```

I want results results as below

```
 
ID   NAME   problem_ID_1   problem_ID_2 problem_ID_3 date_of_entry_1    date_of_entry_2  date_of_entry_3   elem_id_1  elem_id_2 elem_id_3   staff_id_1 staff_id_2  staff_id_3
```

problem_id, date_of entry,elem_id, staff_id are all dynamic. Can you please give me a idea of  how I should do this using pivot function or any other way.

Comment: This is on SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
I have done for two column `problem_ID and date_of_entry` you can add the other two column in pivot.

fiidle demo here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef8e8e/1

```
CREATE TABLE #Products
  (
     ID            INT,
     NAME          VARCHAR(30),
     problem_ID    INT,
     date_of_entry DATE,
     elem_id       VARCHAR(30),
     staff_id      INT
  );

INSERT INTO #Products
VALUES      (1,'abc',456,'2014/12/12',789,32),
            (1,'abc',768,'2014/12/01',896,67),
            (1,'abc',897,'2014/02/14',875,98),
            (2,'bcd',723,'2014/02/17',287,09),
            (2,'bcd',923,'2014/09/13',879,01),
            (2,'bcd',878,'2014/08/23','hgd',34)

DECLARE @problm         VARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @daofenty_id    VARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @aggproblm      VARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @aggdaofenty_id VARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @sql            NVARCHAR(max)

SET @problm = (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename('problm'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY problem_ID)))
                               + ','
               FROM   #Products
               FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @aggproblm = (SELECT DISTINCT ' max('
                                  + Quotename('problm'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY problem_ID)))
                                  + ') problm'
                                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY problem_ID))
                                  + ','
                  FROM   #Products
                  FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @daofenty_id =(SELECT DISTINCT
                     + Quotename('daofenty_id'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY date_of_entry)))
                     + ','
                   FROM   #Products
                   FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @aggdaofenty_id = (SELECT DISTINCT + ' max('
                                        + Quotename('daofenty_id'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY date_of_entry)))
                                        + ') daofenty_id'
                                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY date_of_entry))
                                        + ','
                       FROM   #Products
                       FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @problm = LEFT(@problm, Len(@problm) - 1)
SET @daofenty_id = LEFT(@daofenty_id, Len(@daofenty_id) - 1)
SET @aggproblm = LEFT(@aggproblm, Len(@aggproblm) - 1)
SET @aggdaofenty_id = LEFT(@aggdaofenty_id, Len(@aggdaofenty_id) - 1)
SET @sql = 'SELECT Id,name,' + @aggproblm + ','
           + @aggdaofenty_id + '
           FROM (select * from (SELECT ''problm''+convert(varchar(50),row_number() over(partition by ID order by problem_ID)) problm_id, ''daofenty_id''+convert(varchar(50),row_number() over(partition by ID order by date_of_entry)) daofenty_id ,
 ''elemid''+convert(varchar(50),row_number() over(partition by ID order by elem_id)) elemid ,   ''staffid''+convert(varchar(50),row_number() over(partition by ID order by staff_id)) staffid,*
      FROM #Products) A

      ) AS T

      PIVOT

     (max(problem_id) FOR problm_id IN

     (' + @problm + ')) AS P1

      PIVOT

      (max(date_of_entry) FOR daofenty_id IN

     ('
           + @daofenty_id + ')) AS P1
         group by id,name'

--PRINT @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

to limit the no. of columns

```
SET @problm = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Quotename('problm'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY problem_ID)))
                                   + ','
                   FROM   #Products
                   FOR XML PATH(''))
```

Similarly do the same for other columns..

Comment: pradeep,        can you tell me how can I use pivot function to get the same result

Comment: @Var - I didnt get u what same result u need..I have used pivot function if u have doubts check the fiddle demo

Comment: is there anyway I can restrict the no.of dynamic columns to be created? using row_number.

Comment: @Var - SET problm = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Quotename('problm'....FROM #Products FOR XML PATH('')). like this you need to do for all other columns

Comment: @Var - check the code now to limit the no. of columns

Comment: I have to use dense_rank function instead of row_number for my code. when I use TOP N to select top n columns it's randomly picking the columns like it's picking prblm1,prblm5,prblm9, instead of prblm1,prblm2,prblm3. So how can I fix this?.

Comment: @Var - its working perfectly check the demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1b9a/1

Comment: I'm not saying it's not working. I used dense_rank() instead of row_number because  i'm getting the following error when I use row_number()  "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements". so how should I get the top n columns when I use dense_rank().

Comment: i think it's randomly picking because we are converting it to varchar. so following is the sequence of columns i'm seeing prblm1,prblm10,prblm11,prblm2,prblm20,prblm3..... so what should i do

Comment: @Var "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements" This error is not because of ROW_NUMBER(). In final dynamic sql query the no. of. columns list in select is more than 4096. U should not use dense rank.

Comment: i got this error when i used row_number() thats y i changed it to dense_rank() and i dont have that error now.  it's randomly picking because we are converting it to varchar. so following is the sequence of columns i'm seeing prblm1,prblm10,prblm11,prblm2,prblm20,prblm3..... so what should i do

Comment: @var - try this 'FROM   #Products order by id'

Comment: @var sorry its not id. 'FROM #Products order by problmid'

Comment: @Var - will u get two same problem_id for same id.

Comment: I'm getting this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified"

Comment: @Var Thats y i asked you will u get two same problem_id for same id. if not remove the distinct keyword

Comment: I removed distinct and i'm getting problem1 multiple times before problem2(this is also repeating multiple times). So what should I do